# Typed configuration class not working in Blazor auto rendering mode pages (and need tips on good learning resources on auto rendering mode)

Tags: configuration, blazor, blazor-server-side, blazor-webassembly

I am learning Blazor and am currently working on a personal project using auto rendering mode (aka, interactive auto). Hope some of you expert users can help me with some rookie questions.

Is there a rule of thumb on what **pages \ components** go server side and what client side? I have problems figuring this out. Also, there is lots of information online on the other rendering modes, but no practical examples on the new auto rendering mode, other than generic explanations on how it works. I haven't found anything on Github. Does anyone know of a Github repository, book or any valid content on auto rendering mode?

When working with configuration settings I prefer to use a typed class rather than reading appsettings.json values this way: `Config["NameOfVariable"]`

So, what I did is to create an AppSettings class, bind it at load time and register it in the container. I have a doubt whether I should register the class and relative interface as singleton or scoped, but right now I have a more important problem. This approach works perfectly in the backend of the application, whenever I inject the interface all the settings are there. However, when I inject the interface in a front-end page (server side) all the properties are null. This is how I bind the class at load time:

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
var appSettings = new AppSettings();
var configuration = builder.Configuration;
configuration.Bind(appSettings);
builder.Services.Configure<AppSettings>(configuration);
builder.Services.AddSingleton<IAppSettings, AppSettings>();
var validationResult = appSettings.Validate();

if (validationResult.Failed)
   throw new ValidationException(validationResult.FailureMessage);

etc...
```

Any idea on what is wrong with this approach?

Answer (score 1):

Typed configuration.

```cs
LocalConfiguration localConfiguration = builder.Configuration.Get<LocalConfiguration>() 
    ?? throw new Exception(message: "Unable to load configuration.");
builder.Services.AddSingleton(_ => localConfiguration);
```

Much easier.

Create a class for root object and any sub classes you wish to load for example:

```cs
public class LocalConfiguration
{
    public string? ApplicationTitle { get; set; }
    public HubConfiguration? Hub {  get; set; }
}

public class HubConfiguration
{
    public string? Endpoint { get; set; }
}
```

`appsettings.json`

```json
{
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "DefaultConnection": "Server=..."
  },
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft.AspNetCore": "Warning"
    }
  },
  "AllowedHosts": "*",
  "ApplicationTitle": "My App",
  "Hub": {
    "Endpoint" : "messages"
  }
}
```

As you can see you only have to map the properties you are interested in. In the WebAssembly client create a `wwwroot` folder if there isn't one, place the `appsettings.json` there. Nothing is secure in a clients browser, something to remember here.

Comment: Should I use appsettings.json in the server side project only for the backend and the one in the client side project for the front-end?

Comment: If it's not confidential sure put it in the client. If its more important request it from the server via https. You can have appsettings in both the servers is secure the client is not. IMHO the only sensitive information a client should deal with is the login process. Blazor 8 employes antiforgery tokens in the account page forms which are SSR.

Comment: In webassembly I typically only have things like the application tittle, log levels or endpoint configurations which can change for deployments.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a rule of thumb on what pages \ components go server side and what client side?

Yes, any component that is using either `InteractiveWebAssembly` or `InteractiveAuto` should be placed in the Client project.
Because they will be run on WebAssembly they need to be loaded as Wasm or IL into the Browser. And that is what the Client project is for.

Any Component that will only run on the server (`InteractiveServer` or none, static) could probably also be placed in the Client but that would be wasteful. So keep those in the base (Server) project.

When you create a new project from the standard "Blazor Web App" and select Interactivity=WebAssembly and Location=Global then all components (except App and Error) are placed in the Client project.

Conversely, when you select Interactivity=Server or None then there won't even be a Client project, because nothing needs to be there.

In a mixed mode app the Server project has a dependency on the Client and can use the compiled Client components. On the server Blazor uses the compiled DLL, in the browser the same code from a Webcil file.  That is how InteractiveAuto works.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but it is not clear to me is how to decide what goes server side and what client side. How do I decide what to place on either side? Let's pretend I have to make a dashboard, is it better to have the page server side or client side? What I miss is some guidelines on what goes where.

Comment: You first have to decide on a [RenderMode](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/render-modes?view=aspnetcore-8.0#render-modes). Quite a topic but lots of articles available. After that the placement is easy.